# External Junction Object Rearchitecture

Tags: soql, externalid, junction-object

Currently we have a junction object between a standard object and a custom object.

Our SOQL queries are pretty straight forward for example

```
SELECT Id, Date, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName, Plan__r.Name 
FROM ContactPlan__c
```

We are moving this junction object to an external source. We will need to refactor our queries because `Contact` and `Plan` are no longer lookups, but now text fields.

Is there a way to create a `JOIN`? Something similar to this sql query

```
SELECT CP.Id, CP.Date, C.FirstName, C.LastName, P.Name 
FROM ContactPlan__x CP 
INNER JOIN Contact C
ON C.Id = CP.Contact__c
INNER JOIN Plan__c P
ON P.Id = CP.Plan__c
```

Or will this refactor require separate queries to obtain the Contact and Plan object information?

Comment: Joins are supported in apex, one relationship field. I believe you need to write separate queries to obtain contact and plan records

Comment: Why can't your external system do joins? Otherwise, you'll have to do your joins manually in apex (via some maps and list iterators).